# CMake library linking order

Tags: gcc, cmake

I have following libraries `lib_A`, `lib_B`, `lib_C`, `lib_D`. I am doing something like this in my CMake files (order is important):

1. `ADD_LIBRARY(lib_A)`
2. `ADD_LIBRARY(lib_B)`
3. `ADD_LIBRARY(lib_C)`
4. `ADD_LIBRARY(lib_D)`
5. `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(lib_B lib_C)`
6. `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(lib_A lib_B)`
7. `ADD_EXECUTABLE(Exec)`
8. `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(exec lib_A)`
9. `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(exec lib_D)`

This results in following linker command.

```
linker -llib_A -llib_D -llib_B -llib_C
```

Q1. Why are `lib_B` and `lib_C` after `lib_D`?

Q2. When I change CMake a little bit and do something like this:

8. `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(lib_A lib_D)`
9. `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(exec lib_A)`

then linking order is like this:

```
linker -llib_A -llib_B -llib_C -llib_D
```

Here, `lib_B` and `lib_C` are before `lib_D`. It means that `target_link_libraries` works differently for executable targets and library targets. Am I right?

The problem here is that `lib_B` and `lib_C` also depend on `lib_D`, but I don't want to make `target_link_libraries(lib_B lib_D)` and `target_link_libraries(lib_C lib_D)`, because I have more of such cases, and I would have to do it manually for each library.
Of course doing like in Q2 solves the problem but:

Q3 - Is this order guaranteed somehow by CMake or it is just a fortuity?

Thank you

Comment: Not sure about the difference in order between exes and libs, but if B and C both depend on D, you should really specify that.

Comment: Problem is that B and C are logically part of platform indpendent A and A whole depends on platform lib D. I know I should do this but I have plenty of them and doing it manually will make a lot of efforts to maintain it and providing some automatic solution will increase complexity of my cmake based build system. Another issue is that when I will explicitly set this D dependency to each platform independent lib, it will result that D will be listed on linker list a lot of times.

Comment: I have the same issue with external library - boost for example. I would like to avoid setting dependency to boost in each library.

Comment: @user2301299 The only thing I can suggest is to create a list of external libraries that you link to all of your targets, in order to compact your `target_link_libraries` for each library. BTW, if you link to a dynamic library that is not necessary, the linker will understand that and remove the dependency: not really clean, but you can decide if you want to leave with that

Comment: @user2301299 *"This results in following linker command."* -- Is there a way to generate the linker command or you just know that that's how it should be? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just link `lib_B` and `lib_C` to `lib_D`, it's worth the effort (I can tell by experience), otherwise you will have big troubles, for example if you try to install your program. `lib_C` and `lib_D` should have all their symbols solved when you are finished creating their library files, before linking them to any other library.

By the way, you can compact your `target_link_libraries` in one line per target, like:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(exec lib_A lib_D)
```

And, if exec doesn't depend directly on `lib_D`, you can avoid linking it if you have correctly linked `lib_A` to `lib_D`.

Anyway, regarding Q1: even if the order is guaranteed by CMake, it is not guaranteed the way *your linker* will treat it, you are going to suffer pain if you rely on that

Comment: Thank you for answers. I have decided that I will add the dependency automatically to each library. It will solve another issue. Some of those libraries are shared across a number of executables. Keeping dependencies at the level of each library, i don't have to worry about unresolved symbols at the time of linking those executables.